# JavaScript, add div block

Tags: javascript, css

in function below i'm trying to add div block, but i can't set left position. alert function show message '600px'. on my screen this block has another position.

```
function show(){            
    if(document.getElementById('div1') == null){
        var div1 = document.createElement('div');
        div1.style.left = '600px';
        document.body.appendChild(div1);
        alert(div1.style.left);
    }
}
```

my first question here. so i don't know how to add code style

Comment: Use JQuery! It's your friend!

Comment: Don't use jQuery for trivial things, it is a massive library with abstractions that often get in the way of understanding what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `left` property only applies to elements which are *positioned*. For an element to be positioned, it must have a `position` property with a value other than `static` (which is the default).

Set it to `relative`, `fixed` or `absolute` as per your needs.

Answer (score 2):

You're not going to see anything visual on the page with your example for a couple reasons. First, your div does not contain anything, so it has no height or width. And second, you cannot position an element in the manner you are trying because it does not have display attribute absolute or relative. Try something like this:

```
function show(){

    if(document.getElementById('div1') == null){
      var div1 = document.createElement('div');
      div1.innerHTML = 'hi there';
      div1.style.left = '600px';
      div1.style.position = 'absolute';
      document.body.appendChild(div1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `div` will have 0 height/width as there is no child content. Use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) or [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML) to add content to the `div`.

Also, the [`left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left) property will not apply unless you set the [positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) to `relative` or `absolute`. This also goes for the other sides (`right`, `top` and `bottom`).